# Декомпиляция APK в проект Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, apk, декомпиляция

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность декомпилировать APK файл обратно в проект Unity. Со скриптами C#, настройками и прочим-прочим.
Знаю, что много информации есть с декомпиляцией в форматы Java - вроде dex2jar.
Интересуют по большей части скрипты C# и их привязки, которые находятся в этом APK

Comment: Можно http://devxdevelopment.com/UnityUnpacker
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score -1):

В проект юнити нельзя. Но код можно посмотреть с помощью некоторых декомпиляторов. Например [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Answer (score -1):

Можно `unity ripper`, и код будет доступен, если моно компиляция

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]